# Concat child records in parent SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

To my best knowledge of MySQL this not a possible thought in this case would be helpful.

We want to `select` a record in a parent table and concat (something like that) the child rows in the  `select`. Here in obviously wrong MySQL but to illustrate what we want to achieve.

```
SELECT parentattr, 
       CONCAT (
               SELECT name 
               FROM child 
               WHERE child.parentId = parent.id)) as allchildernames
FROM parent
```

Comment: Try using [`GROUP_CONCAT(name)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in your inner query (and drop the `CONCAT()` in the outer query =])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need a `GROUP BY`, plus you need to specify exactly which name is being concatenated.

```
SELECT parentattr1, parentattr2, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name ORDER By c.name)
FROM parent p
LEFT JOIN child c ON parentId = c.id
GROUP BY parentattr1, parentattr2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using GROUP_CONCAT (), here are [examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

You also have an extra `)` after parent.id.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```sql
SELECT parentattr, GROUP_CONCAT(child.name SEPARATOR ', ') as allchildernames
FROM parent, child 
WHERE child.parentId = parent.id 
GROUP BY parent.id
```